# Option for VB.Net in Visual Studio to directly jump to variable's datatype after new operator in intellisense list missing

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

Is there an option for VB.Net in Visual Studio to directly jump to variable datatype's after new operator in intellisense list? (Please don't give Add-in option like Resharper or CodeRush. Plain Native Visual Studio settings would suffice)

**Scenario**
I come from C# background and have habit of writing like

```
Application a = new
```

As soon as I press space bar after new operator, the intellisense directly jumps to Application class in the list of intellisense options like this

[image]

(I understand that this feature fails in implicit declaration (with `var` keyword) and it has to because Intellisense (at compile time) does not know datatype but it works in explicit declaration as above.

But AFAIK this option is absent from VB.Net like this

[image]

Even though it's an explicit declaration.

Now is there an option in visual studio that can be turned on so that this thing works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not configurable.

When you write it like this, the editor assumes that you intentionally want a different class type in the New expression.  Because if you didn't then you would have written it like this:

```
 Dim d As New ...
```

Where the IntelliSense window pops up as soon as you typed New.  Note that there is no equivalent for this syntax in C#.  Notable is that this behavior was altered in VS2012 and now works like the C# IntelliSense.